# Cordova and ios-deploy causes builds to fail with "codesign exit code 1"/ "permission denied"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, codesign

I'm working on a Cordova based mobile application, and wanted to make use of the Cordova CLI's ability to deploy and run my mobile app right from the command line, without having to go into XCode to do the build

When doing:

```
cordova run ios --device
```

Cordova graciously tells you that you should install the [ios-deploy](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy) node module. I did so following the steps on their GIT site.

When I next tried to do a run, I started to get codesign errors, specifically:

```
/Users/blahblah/platforms/ios/build/device/myApp.app: Permission denied
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I couldn't get the code signing to work from Terminal, and worse, going back into XCode resulted in the same error!

Fortunately the error messages says it all: permission denied;  I was able to correct this by popping back into Terminal and running a chmod on my entire app folder, i.e.:

```
chmod -R a+rwx myApp
```

I could then go back into XCode and get the project building and deploying again (whew!), however if I tried to do the deploy via the Cordova CLI, then same issue would occur.

It seems like the ios-deploy and / or cordova is messing around with the folder permissions, but I'm not sure how to correct this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
To be clear, I am able to successfully sign the app within XCode if I first go into Terminal, and then into the platforms/ios folder and perform a chmod -R a+rwx on the "www" folder.

The problem I'm having is trying to get this to build / sign successfully from the command line.

I've done some further diagnosis, and it seems that the problem is with the Cordova CLI itself, and not with ios-deploy;  when I execute:

```
cordova prepapre
```

It copies my "www" folder over to the "platforms/ios/www", however it changes the permissions when doing so from everyone having write access (i.e.: drwxrwxrwx) to only my user having write access i.e.: (drwxr-xr-x)

It seems that this is fouling up the codesign application, and is causing my permission denied errors above.

I'm just hoping someone knows how I can work around this, or what I might be doing wrong with my build - I'd prefer not to have to go into XCode to do these builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that the Cordova CLI is working just fine, as is the ios-deploy npm package.

The problem turns out to be within the solution itself, and has nothing to do with the tools.

I am using the Ionic framework within this particular Cordova application, and their framework installs some "after_prepare" hooks (within the hooks folder) which attempt to help prepare / clean up some extraneous files prior to the build.

One of these hooks (named "020_remove_sass_from_platform.js") was trying to help out by cleaning up unneeded SASS files prior to the build in order to reduce the size of the compiled app.

Unfortunately this hook was adjusting the folder permissions (I guess in order to ensure the delete could succeed), and this was the cause of the "www" folder's permissions changing during a "cordova prepare".

I deleted the hooks, and now the Cordova CLI builds and signs the APK as expected, and the ios-deploy package pushes it to the device, all without using XCode.

Hope this can be of some help to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Check the CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY property in your build settings. Is your provisioning profile selected there?

You also need to enter a valid bundle identifier in your apps .plist.

The identifier has to match the one you provided when generating the profile.

Comment: I actually am able to successfully sign the app within XCode;  the problem I'm having is getting this working from the command line using the Cordova CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm
```